# receive email using matlab

Tags: email, matlab

I am working on a project where people can email the name of a color (ie 'red') to a dedicated e mail address and then change the color of attached lights to that particular color.  I have everything finished except for the email connectivity.  I know that there is a built in sendmail function but not a check mail function in matlab.  I read about some ways of doing it using java, but i'm not entirely sure how to do that.  The email account used will be a web-based gmail account.

thanks.

Comment: I know it's not really relevant, but I wonder why MATLAB as a choice of platform for such application.. Wouldn't it be easier with a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably to call out to an external script, such as those
[shown here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3380/check-your-unread-gmail-from-the-command-line), and capture the output using the systemc() Matlab function.  Note that the first line of the email is available in the atom feed in the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no mail server application for Matlab - but that doesn't mean you can't roll your own.

Question the first: can you let a normal mail server handle this, and then trigger a run of a matlab program as a result?  Or does the matlab program need to hanndle it itself?

If you just need to trigger a matlab program, you might look into something like procmail - not sure how hard it would be.

If you really need a matlab SMTP server, you could use something like: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab

You'd have to:
A) implement SMTP in matlab.  It's probably not as hard as it sounds - it's called SIMPLE Mail Transfer Protocol for a reason.  Start with: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt
B) configure DNS to have an MX record for the domain in question that points to the server where the matlab app is run
C) trigger the light change when an email when the mail is received.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PNet](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcpudpip-toolbox-2-0-6).
With this little toolbox you can do any UDP or TCP communication.
So you can implement IMAP or POP3 protocol to get your mails. (A PNet already contains a pop3 demo for email retrieval.)